# What exactly is _auth_user_id (in connection with django-auth-ldap)?

Tags: django, session, authentication, django-auth-ldap

In Django you can read `_auth_user_id` from `request.session` dictionary after you authenticate and log in user. As I understand in "normal" conditions (standard authentication backend) it should be user id (pk).

But what is `_auth_user_id` when I'm using `django-auth-ldap` as authentication backend? It returns integers but there is no such values in my LDAP database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Django authentication backend--django-auth-ldap included--ultimately returns an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.User` on a successful authentication. `django.contrib.sessions`, in turn, knows only about these user objects; it doesn't know or care which backend produced them. So `request.session['_auth_user_id']` should be a User pk regardless of your backend. As a rule, of course, you would access `request.user` for convenience.

If you're using django-auth-ldap and you need to get back to the LDAP user, you can look at `request.user.ldap_user`. See the documentation for details and performance considerations.